# Conditional Formatting in different sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a 13x13 table of data on a worksheet that is comprised of links to another sheet.

For example the first row of 13 looks like:

```
=Sheet1!R7  =Sheet1!R20 =Sheet1!R21 =Sheet1!R22 =Sheet1!R23 =Sheet1!R24  =Sheet1!R25    =Sheet1!R26 =Sheet1!R27 =Sheet1!R28 =Sheet1!R29 =Sheet1!R30 =Sheet1!R31
```

I want to do conditional formatting over the entire table for when data from column R and column C of the same row are equal and >0.

For example;

When Sheet1!R7 is equal to Sheet1!C7 and >0, color the sheet 2 table (that has the link) red.

When Sheet1!R20 is equal to Sheet1!C20 and >0, color the sheet 2 table red and so on.

I would also like to repeat the process with a different colored fill if R == L and >0 but I can just use the same formula once I know how.

My attempt was =AND(Sheet1!R7=Sheet1!C7,Sheet1!C7>0).

This works for the single cell, but I'd like a way to do the whole table at once.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT for clairty:**

*I'm sure I'm not explaining it too well.

To put it simply, I have 2 columns of numbers, let's say A1:A169 and B1:B169.
I want to take the larger number from A and B for each row (A10 vs B10 etc, I used MAX function for this) and dump the output in column C.

I then aim to color code column C based on whether the number comes from column A or B. Red for A, yellow for B (no color for <0).

So far I have achieved all of this, I have the data sitting in a column color coded.

My problem comes in that I want to have the 169 numbers in column C in a more readable format, I.E. in a 13x13 grid table. I don't know how to do this and keep the color coding!*

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I can offer you some possible solution.
Lets say you have sheet1 and sheet2. In sheet2, you have links to 
sheet1 as you mentioned. And my understanding is that you want to color
the sheet2 (the entire table?) as red if a certain condition is met.
This is how it might be done.

1. In sheet 2, create a formula for a cell which reflects your condition. Lets say that is =IF(Sheet1!A1="foo", 1, 0). You can add your AND conditions in that if statement. So that cell will contain 1 if the condition is met and 0 if not met.
2. Select the range of cells in sheet2. Click conditional formatting. Select "use a formula to determine which cells to format". Enter the condition for the calculated value in sheet2. For example, in sheet2, my cell G1 is the result of the formula =IF(Sheet1!A1="foo", 1, 0). So if the value of G1 is 1 then I want to color the range Red.
   [image]
   So in essense, we are using a formula to calculate the value of a cell and using that value 
   as a condition to format a range of cells in Sheet2.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got your example working :)
However, I'd like to color each cell (169 of them) based on a different condition/cell from sheet1. Well the condition is the same, the only difference is the row numbers.

For example
Let's say I have Sheet2!A1 dependant on Sheet1!A1, I don;t want to color the whole table. Instead only color Sheet2!A1.
Likewise Sheet2!A7 might be dependant on Sheet1!A7 and so on for each cell.

I guess I'm left to manually make many many conditions?